# Approximate-GCD problem in polynomials

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, lattice-crypto

I am trying to understand the two main hard problems that have been explored in the context of homomorphic encryption: Learning with Errors Problem (LWE) and the Approximate-GCD (AGCD) problem. I have some idea of the LWE problem and its variants such as the Ring-LWE. Recently, I have been reading about the Approximate-GCD problem from articles such as: https://eprint.iacr.org/2009/616.pdf, https://perso.ens-lyon.fr/damien.stehle/downloads/AGCD.pdf. I would like to know if there is also some literature on a polynomial version of the AGCD problem (like Ring-LWE was formulated from LWE), that is, if the AGCD problem has been shown to be 'hard' over polynomial rings as well.